# Convert nan to Zero when numpy dtype is “object” within custom transformer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pipeline

I am reading a csv file that has numeric columns that have empty space using pandas read_csv.
I am passing the read  data frame into a column transformer which calls the custom transformer.
The dataframe is converted to a numpy array and passed to the above customer transformer.

It is within this transformer that I am  trying to replace  the nan values which I have not been able to do so

Digging into SO I found all these solution nothing has worked so far

The following is my custom transformer

```
class Xfrmer_replacenum(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
        this transformer does the global repplace within the dataframe
        replace 365243 spcific to this case study with 0
        replace +/-inf , nan with zero
    """
    # constructor
    def __init__(self):
        #we are not going to use this 
        self._features = None
        
    #Return self 
    def fit(self, X,y=None  ):
        return self
    
    def transform(self,X,y=None):     
        print(X)
        print(X.dtype)
        X = X.astype(float)
        #replace high values with zero
        #or col in X.columns:
        #for col in X.columns:
        X[X==365243.0] = 0
        X[X==365243] = 0
        #np.where(X_==X_,X_,0)
        #np.nan_to_num(X[0, :].astype(np.float64))
        #X = np.nan_to_num(X.astype(np.float64))
        #X = X.astype(str).replace('nan', 0).astype(float)
        #np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.replace(',',''),1,1)(X).astype(float)
        np.array([v.replace(',', '') for v in X], dtype=np.float32)
        print('replaced values')
        #X=X.replace([np.inf,-np.inf],np.nan)
        #X=X.replace(np.nan,0)    
        print('all replace',X.shape)
        print('just before ret',X[X==365243])
        np.savetxt("./output/prvapln_colxfrmr_onlynum.csv", X,fmt='%s',delimiter=",")
        return X
```

This is the way I am using the custom transformer within the column transformer

```
    lst_cols =["ID1","ID2","AMT_CREDIT_SUM","AMT_CREDIT_SUM_DEBT","AMT_CREDIT_SUM_LIMIT","AMT_CREDIT_SUM_OVERDUE"]

        lst_idx =[]

    lst_all_cols = X_train.columns.values.tolist()

        for col in lst_cols:
                
            idx = lst_all_cols.index(col)
            lst_idx.append(idx)

        preprcs_stg1_pipln = ColumnTransformer( transformers = [
                                                    ( 'repl_pipln', Xfrmer_replacenum(),lst_idx)],
                                                    remainder='passthrough')
```

These are the various things I have tried to use in my Custom Transformer:

```
        np.where(X_==X_,X_,0)
        
        X = np.nan_to_num(X.astype(np.float64))

        X = X.astype(str).replace('nan', 0).astype(float)

        np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.replace(',',''),1,1)(X).astype(float)

        np.array([v.replace(',', '') for v in X], dtype=np.float32)
```

My data looks like this

```
[[2163253 154602 4187.34 -1230.0 -1226.0 0.0]
 [1676258 433469 22242.825 -1343.0 -1334.0 1.0]
 [2075578 418383 7656.705 -2341.0 -2332.0 0.0]
 [1548737 391536 21416.85 nan nan nan]
 [2721491 292308 3959.1 -2604.0 -2601.0 1.0]
 [2595549 432416 3951.225 -540.0 -537.0 0.0]]
object
```

For the ones that have replace I get this error

**AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'**

**My Question**

How do I replace nan in the above  ndarray of dtype object ?

Comment: Can you replace the values in the Pandas DataFrame? df['ColumnName'].fillna(value=0) If not, please share more of your code.

Comment: I have added the necessary code. Due to data leak issues I have to use only pipelines and transformers

Comment: `a[np.isnan(a)] = 1`?

Comment: a[np.isnan(a)] = 1 thanks this worked . Can you make this the answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to find all the np.nan columns and then set them to a follow using the following code

```
a[np.isnan(a)] = 1 # or whatever value
```